# Swift: Checking conformance of Foundation (NS)Errors to a custom protocol

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

Use case:

To be able to log errors, we conform them to a certain protocol.
This seems to work for custom errors, however, checking or casting Foundation errors (such as URLError) to this protocol, seems to be failing.

I have no clue what's different here.

In this example: We have a viewmodel that does an operation that can lead to an error.
We want to log this error with our logger.

Example:

```swift
// Protocol that makes an error loggable

protocol LoggableError: Error {
    var message: String { get }
}

// Our custom error:

enum CustomError: Error {
    case someError
}

extension CustomError: LoggableError {
    var message: String {
        "Some error occurred"
    }
}

// URL error conforming to our LoggableError:

extension URLError: LoggableError {
    var message: String {
        "Some network error occurred"
    }
}

// The logger

protocol LoggerProtocol {
    func handle(error: some Error)
}

class Logger: LoggerProtocol {
    func handle(error: some Error) {
        guard let error = error as? LoggableError else { fatalError("Cast failed") }
        print(error.message)
    }
}

// The view model

class ViewModel {
    private let logger: LoggerProtocol

    init(logger: LoggerProtocol) {
        self.logger = logger
    }

    func doSomething() {
        do {
            try doSomethingDangerous()
        } catch {
            logger.handle(error: error)
        }
    }

    private func doSomethingDangerous() throws {
        throw CustomError.someError // this works
        // throw URLError(.notConnectedToInternet) // this triggers the fatalError
    }
}

// Trigger

let viewModel = ViewModel(logger: Logger())
viewModel.doSomething()
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or why this isn't working?
7 years of Swift development, I still don't seem to get my head around protocols :D

Comment: What Swift version are you using? Your code is working perfectly fine for me even if I swap the 2 throws in `doSomethingDangerous` using both Swift 5.7 and 5.8. [See](https://swiftfiddle.com/radfu4cgbffz5nu6hg3jz3luwq)

Comment: Btw your question title is wrong, `URLError` is not an `NSError`.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Interesting, I can reproduce the issue using a playground in Xcode 14.3

Comment: Using Xcode 14.2 atm, Swift 5.7.2

Comment: Interesting, indeed, this crashes when building with Xcode 14.2 & 14.3, but not in that SwiftFiddle/Linux test environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I consider this a bug in Foundation, and recommend opening a Feedback about it. But what you're encountering is due to the tricky ways that NSError is dealt with on Darwin (which is why you don't see this problem on Linux).

Many Foundation errors are really just wrappers around NSError. Even though they have their own Swift type, they do not survive round-tripping through an existential:

```
print(type(of: CustomError.someError))              // CustomError
print(type(of: CustomError.someError as any Error)) // CustomError

print(type(of: URLError(.notConnectedToInternet)))              // URLError
print(type(of: URLError(.notConnectedToInternet) as any Error)) // **NSError**
```

(Note that this is not related to enums vs structs. If you change CustomError to a struct, it still works fine. The problem is the NSError that you don't see.)

Similar problems happen when coming through `some`. The ObjC and Swift types wind up not matching. There is magic bridging of Foundation errors to make them more "Swifty." But it's a pretty leaky abstraction, and this is a bug.

If possible you should conform NSError to LoggableError. That will fix this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the help! At least I know I'm still sane. :)

Unfortunately, conforming NSError to LoggableError seems to result in all type checks giving this compiler warning: `Conditional cast from 'any Error' to 'any LoggableError' always succeeds`.

I'll file a radar with this code-snippet in the hopes that it will get fixed once.

Comment: Ah, because every Error can bridge to NSError I suspect. You may explore putting a default implementation of LoggableError on Error (or on LoggableError itself) and just accept all errors. You may wind up using `as` rather than `as?`.

Comment: For future reference or any Apple engineers that find this issue: FB12114186